# Porting from VS6 to VS2012: return values screwed up

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-6

While porting a VS6 project to VC++2012 environment, I'm experiencing a strange behavior...

Let's say I've the following

```
// double AreaIco = 75.0;
// double theApp.m_GlobalScale = 0.25;
double ToLong(double); // elsewhere defined
double result = ToLong(AreaIco * theApp.m_GlobalScale * theApp.m_GlobalScale);
```

What I find is that the ToLong function gets "0" as input parameter

This also happens if I try to introduce temporary variables:

```
double temp1 = AreaIco * theApp.m_GlobalScale;
double temp2 = temp1 * theApp.m_GlobalScale;
AreaIcoInScala = ToLong(temp2);
```

Both temp1 and temp2 evaluate to either 0 or a denormalized value.

However, trying to evaluate the expression in QuickWatch returns correct value.

Does anyone have any clue for such a behavior? I fear there's some ancient bug in the code, which has been covered since now by somethink in VS6...

Thanks anyone for support, anyway.

Comment: What is ToLong? Did you forget a tag?

Comment: What is the parameter type for `ToLong`? And what is the difference between `theApp.m_GlobalScale` and `theApp.GlobalScale`?

Comment: The problem is obviously with `ToLong`, which you didn't show. Where and how is this function defined? The only `ToLong` I know is a .NET function, which was therefore not available in VS6.

Comment: I'm sorry, that function is defined in the project. However the issue is not there, since 
1) the function is actually receiving a wrong input parameter - the multiplication shown in my post evaluates to either 0 or a denormalized value
2) If I try to make the multiplication, assign it to a temporary value (temp1 and temp2) and pass that temporary to the ToLong() function, the temporary itself shows a bad value (either 0 or denormalized); in this case the ToLong is not called at all.

Comment: In which case, the following should also resolve to zero: `double temp1 = 75.0 * 0.25;` and I bet it doesn't. So, there must be something you're not showing us. Have you checked that the operands are not being corrupted after initialisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some futher investigation, we found it was a problem with data structure alignment.
In VS options the Struct Member Alignment was set to 4 bytes, while a #pragma pack 2 was present in one of the source files.

Strange enough, everything worked under VS6, the porting to VS2012 made this issue come out.

Comment: That's because the default packing changed several times between VS releases.